# How exactly does Lambert Conformal Conic projection work?

Tags: coordinate-system, lambert-conformal-conic

I need to transform geographical positions, given as latitude and longitude in WGS 84 (World Geodetic System 1984) (EPSG-Code: 4326) into MGI / Austria Lambert (EPSG-Code: 31287). And I also need to calculate the reverse transformation, from MGI / Austria Lambert back to WGS 84.

MGI / Austria Lambert is a Lambert Conformal Conic (LCC) projection, and I try to find out two things:

- I need an exact formula (or even better: a code snippet in Python) to do the desired calculation. (It would be nice if you could help me with that too, but this is not the main topic of my question.)
- I want to understand how LCC works in detail. This is the main topic of my question.

This is clear to me:

1. Planet Earth is modelled as a rotational ellipsoid (Bessel 1841; a = 6377397.155 m, b = 6356078.963 m).
2. You pick two circles of latitude (in EPSG-31287: 46°N and 49°N). These two circles define a cone. The tip of the cone lies exactly on the axis of rotation of the earth.
3. You project points from the surface of the planet onto this cone.
4. You cut the cone along a straight line that goes through the tip and then unroll the cone on a plane. This results in a map in LCC projection.

My problem is step #3:

It seems clear to me, that all points that lie on the same longitude on the surface of planet earth will be projected onto a straight line on the cone that goes exactly through the tip. But I didn't find any descriptions where exactly on this line the projections will be.

I prepared a sketch. It is a sectional drawing of the earth and the cone. The flattening of the earth ellipsoid is drawn highly exaggerated to better demonstrate that the possibilities I came up are not equal.

[image]

Symbols:

- **O** center of the earth
- **N** North pole
- **S** South pole
- **ϕ₁** and **ϕ₂** The latitudes where the cone and the ellipsoid intersect. (That in my sketch ϕ₁ lies on the equator is just an accident).
- **P** the point on the surface that needs to be projected onto the cone
- **A, B** and **C** Three different projections of **P** on the cone.

**A**
The point A lies exactly in the zenith of P. (The horizon is the tangential plane that touches the planet's surface in the point P, the zenith is the line that is perpendicular to the horizon and points away from the planet.)

**B**
You draw a straight line that goes through O and P. The intersection of this line and the cone is point B.

**C**
Point C is the point on the cone that has the smallest distance from P. The line from P to C hits the cone in a right angle.

Which of the three possible projections is the correct projection when you use LCC projection? Or are all of them wrong, and there is another way to project P onto the cone? Which way is correct?

Comment: Reinventing this particular wheel is closer to reinventing a turbofan engine. Why not just use a projection library and be productive today instead of debugging your code into the new year?

Comment: Ellipsoidal formulas can be difficult to describe, but the code snippet is straightforward if you start with _import pyproj_.

Comment: @Vince: Because I want to understand what I do. How can someone check if the library works correct if nobody understands what is going on?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca: Can you give me those formulas? I want to read them because I want to understand them.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand them: [General Theory of the Lambert Conformal Conic Projection](ftp://ftp.library.noaa.gov/docs.lib/htdocs/rescue/cgs_specpubs/QB275U35no531918.pdf)

Comment: They are summarized, but not explained, in https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470121498.app6

Comment: Hubert, Eat your hart out in the detailed ellipsiodal math in John P. Snyder's seminal work with forward and reverse formulae: https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395